# Add google as my search engine again

Tags: firefox, google-search

Experimentally, I removed google from the list of possible search engines in the search bar on firefox.  Now I can't find it again--apparently so few people need to actually add google that it's pretty much impossible...  How do I get google back in the search bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it.  Click on the dropdown to choose the engine, click on "Manage Search Engines...", and click "restore defaults".

Comment: As of april 2014 Google Chrome doesn't have that option anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, Google disappeared entirely with no way to restore it. The "Manage search engines did not work.

Citing the wonderful answer of Anurag from post
[How to restore the default Google search engine in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/578228/how-to-restore-the-default-google-search-engine-in-chrome/578244#578244)

Go to

```
Settings > Search Engine > Manage search engines > Add (button)
```

Fill in:

```
**Name:** Google
**Keyword:** google.com
```

And paste below code in the URL box:

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}ie={inputEncoding}
```

Hope this works for you as well as it did for me!