# How to restore the default Google search engine in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

How do I revert to the default Google search engine in Chrome?

Most sites have a simple querystring search, like `http://mysite/search/?query=%s`, but Google has some weird query string, and I'm not sure how to restore it.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/667429/how-to-reset-chromes-search-engines-to-default

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can goto

```
Settings > Manage Search Engines
```

in Google Chrome and  you can add Google Search Engine again. Here's how:

1. In the bottom you will find

   ```
   Other Search Engines
   ```

   and below that text boxes for adding a new search engine.
2. Give Name -

   ```
   Google
   ```

   Keyword -

   ```
   google.com
   ```

   and paste the below code in the URL box:

   `{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}ie={inputEncoding}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: No help to me. An installer has managed to overwrite the google:baseURL variable with a link to feed.sonic-search.com, which redirects to search.snapdo.com. Trying to find how I can reset google:baseURL to the correct value. The Google search engine has exactly the text you provide but gets the bad link injected.

Comment: That sounds very much like malware. Try running a scan using malwarebytes to kill any infections.

Comment: New value for Google default: `{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:bookmarkBarPinned}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

Answer (score 8):

Goto Chrome → Settings and click on the `Manage Search Engines` button.

Add new search engine

- Name: `Google`
- Keyword: `google.com`
- Url: `{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}ie={inputEncoding}`

This is what I have set in Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

(My answer from [webapps.SA](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/55309/58244))

If you just want to permanently use google.com (or any other fixed URL) as the search engine, above two methods probably is not what you are looking for. `/ncr` and adding another search engine both breaks the default realtime search functionality. Try this,

1. Close all the Chrome/chromium browsers,
2. go to User Data folder

   - Windows: `users\username\appdata\local\google\chromium\User Data` (or similar - please edit if this is wrong)
   - Linux: `~/.config/chromium/Default`
3. open the file named `LocalState` (windows) or `Preferences` in vim/notepad, and change,

   - `last_known_google_url` and
   - `last_prompted_google_url`
     to whatever the baseURL you want. Ex. `"https://www.google.com/"`
4. Save.

For more info look at this old [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1521#c32).

Comment: On OS X you can find the `last_known_google_url` in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with manually adding/editing the search URL is that it won't restore the built-in behavior fully, specifically the **dynamic autocomplete suggestions based on Google search** because it's an [internal](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/search_engines/prepopulated_engines.json;l=120;drc=a6e30af78c033713e62b16cf8adabc387d4c8f4e) field present in the prepopulated search engines. The only officially documented method is to reset the browser settings, but it'll nuke most of your profile data.

Here's how I've restored just the built-in `Google` engine and kept the profile intact:

1. [Find your `User Data` directory](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).
2. Exit Chrome fully via its menu -> Exit, so that no hidden processes or tray icons remain.
3. Copy/zip the contents of that directory somewhere else so you have a backup just in case.
4. Open `Secure Preferences` file inside the profile directory in a text editor.
5. Delete the text that starts with `"default_search_provider_data":{` and ends with `},`

   Some editors conveniently highlight the closing bracket when the cursor is at the opening `{`.

   Note the comma should be also deleted.

   Make sure you don't reformat the file because its parts are protected by a "hashsum", meaning that changing even one byte there would prompt Chrome to reset all settings. You can open the file in an online JSON beautifier beforehand to have a visual confirmation that you're deleting the correct part.
6. Save the file and start Chrome, go to `chrome://settings` and verify the result.

Yet another nondestructive solution that doesn't involve kinda hackish editing might be to manually add a local policy for [DefaultSearchProviderSuggestURL](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DefaultSearchProviderSuggestURL), and other related keys like DefaultSearchProviderImageURL, DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL.

Comment: In secure preferences, I only have one line:

{"protection":{"macs":{},"super_mac":"E258E3F3F18FA7028417E5C32331279DDBB30BF80AD7FC816960427EBF5230F1"}}

how do I see everything else that's in it?