# Chrome not showing predictions from default search engine (Google)

Tags: google-chrome

I have this problem where Chrome only shows my previous queries/urls and won't show predictions. It was like this all the time I'm using Chrome, which is my primary browser for last 5+ years. I've just recently noticed that predictions from Google is a feature when using another computer where Chrome was running out of the box, i.e. without syncing settings from my profile.

I've searched and [only thing I've found](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en) is that I should have the option "*Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar*" checked, which I do. If I log out as Chrome person, it works, but as soon as I log in and settings sync, it stops working again.

I guess resetting the settings would be an option, but I'd really like to avoid doing that as I don't want to configure everything back. Any other solutions or suggestions?

Comment: If you type in your address bar "chrome://settings/searchEngines" (without the quotes) and hit enter, under the Default search settings can you please post the information for the search provider in Bold?

Comment: @PinchusGelbman: **Google (Default)** | **google.com_** | **http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8**. Btw I'm currently using OS X. I'd say that client=ubuntu is there from the old days when I was using ubuntu.

Comment: I'm also using OS X but I wanted to give you that third column to enter but I already left the office so hopefully someone else could help you in the meantime

Comment: Found this: http://superuser.com/questions/578228/how-to-restore-the-default-google-search-engine-in-chrome. Set it to this, even restarted the browser, but it's still not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution, thanks to @Pinchus Gelbman's suggestion. Next to "*Manage search engines...*" button, there is a dropdown to choose the default search engine. I've noticed that there are 2 named Google and after selecting the other one, it started working.