# Chrome keeps searching using Yahoo

Tags: google-chrome

I type a search term in to the address bar on Chrome and it keeps searching with yahoo on desktop.

Search engine used in the address bar (in settings) is set as Google.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try removing your Chrome user profile.  Be sure you backup the current profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, a couple days later, without touching any additional settings, it started searching Google again.

Answer (score 0):

To manage your search engines, copy this into your search bar:

```
chrome://settings/searchEngines?search=Manage%20search%20engines
```

and pressn "Enter". See if Yahoo! is the default. If so, click on the 3-dot menu icon at the right of the "Google" entry and choose "Make default".

If there is no "Google" entry, you can add it back using instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/578228/how-to-restore-the-default-google-search-engine-in-chrome):

If Google is already your search engine, something fishy is going on.