# Cannot restore default search engine as Google in Chrome despite workarounds

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows-registry, search

I accidentally deleted Google's default search engine and now the only default engine left is Yahoo.

I have tried manually adding it back using the code found here: [How to restore the default Google search engine in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/578228/how-to-restore-the-default-google-search-engine-in-chrome)

{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:bookmarkBarPinned}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}

I have also deleted he text that starts with "default_search_provider_data":{ and ends with
} in Secure Preferences file, but the default is still Yahoo!

Lastly, I even made a registry file that forces it to default:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"DefaultSearchProviderEnabled"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSearchProviderName"="Google"
"DefaultSearchProviderNewTabURL"="https://www.google.com/"
"DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL"="https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}"
"DefaultSearchProviderSuggestURL"="https://www.google.com/complete/search?output=chrome&q={searchTerms}"

and it still defaults to Yahoo!

I cannot just reset my Chrome settings because that will erase the years of work I did to customize my search engines (it has at least 500 custom search shortcuts and there's no easy way to export/import them)

Any help please?

Comment: What if you start without extensions? Also AFAIK resetting Chrome does not wipe bookmarks.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear this wasn't caused by any malware, but my own doing as I accidentally deleted all the default search engines except Yahoo. 

Also, custom search engines are not the same as bookmarks. I need a way to get back my custom search engines if it's to be reset.